# How do I stop iCal from always asking for a password?

Tags: password, ical

I have several (webcal) subscription calendars on my iCal.  Two of them require passwords stored in my keychain.  At regular intervals, iCal will ask for my keychain password.  Is there a way to set up iCal so that it behaves the way Mail.app does, that is, one types the password once when the app is fired and from then on it just uses it?

My keychain is set to unlock when I log in; the webcal items in the keychain are set to allow any application to access the item.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the following menu in Keychain Access app?

Open Keychain Access app (use spotlight!), select your login Keychain and in the Edit menu:

[image: Edit]

select 'Change Settings for Keychain “login”…’

This brings you the following screen:

[image: Keychain Settings]

If you have either of those, iCal will find the Keychain locked when it tries to sync.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping keep the auto-lock feature.  Mail seems to be able to fetch the passwords from the keychain and use then while I'm logged in to fetch and deliver my email.  Why can't iCal behave the same way?